# How to convert shell output to string in Rust

Tags: shell, get, rust, output

I'm writing a small script in Rust and I need to get the user who is running it. I thought to retrieve the user using a simple process, something like this:

```
let output = Command::new("whoami")
             .output();
let user = output.stdout;
```

I don't know how to convert `user` into a string so that I can use it for `println!`.

Comment: Please note that by executing `whoami` you sacrifice cross-platform compatibility. There appears to be a [`user` crate](https://crates.io/crates/user) exactly for this purpose. Looks pretty inactive to me, though :/

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with that crate